# How to make replace function loops for all the files in the same folder (same directory)?

Tags: loops, replace, vbscript, directory

**I have this VBScript mainly for replace function for multiple text files.**

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' START OF 1st REPORTS ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\rep01_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt", ForReading)

IF objFSO.GetFile("D:\rep01_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt").size <> 0 then    
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "$$$970A1", "SSS970A1",1,1)
strNewText1 = Replace(strNewText, "$$$979A1", "SSS979A1",1,1)
strNewText2 = Replace(strNewText1, "$$$983A1", "SSS983A1",1,1)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\rep01_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText2 

objFile.Close
END IF
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' END OF 1st REPORTS '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' START OF 2nd REPORTS '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\rep01_UnmatchAP_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt", ForReading)

IF objFSO.GetFile("D:\rep01_UnmatchAP_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt").size <> 0 then    
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "$$$970A1", "SSS970A1",1,1)
strNewText1 = Replace(strNewText, "$$$979A1", "SSS979A1",1,1)
strNewText2 = Replace(strNewText1, "$$$983A1", "SSS983A1",1,1)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\rep01_UnmatchAP_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText2 

objFile.Close
END IF
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' END OF 2nd REPORTS ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' START OF 3rd REPORTS  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\rep01_UnmatchAR_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt", ForReading)

IF objFSO.GetFile("D:\rep01_UnmatchAR_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt").size <> 0 then    
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "$$$970A1", "SSS970A1",1,1)
strNewText1 = Replace(strNewText, "$$$979A1", "SSS979A1",1,1)
strNewText2 = Replace(strNewText1, "$$$983A1", "SSS983A1",1,1)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\rep01_UnmatchAR_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText2 

objFile.Close
END IF
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' END OF 3rd REPORTS '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' START OF 4th REPORTS ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\rep01_UnmatchCutOff_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt", ForReading)

IF objFSO.GetFile("D:\rep01_UnmatchCutOff_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt").size <> 0 then    
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "$$$970A1", "SSS970A1",1,1)
strNewText1 = Replace(strNewText, "$$$979A1", "SSS979A1",1,1)
strNewText2 = Replace(strNewText1, "$$$983A1", "SSS983A1",1,1)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("D:\rep01_UnmatchCutOff_" & Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Now - 1), 2) & ".txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText2 

objFile.Close
END IF
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' END OF 4th REPORTS '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

But this kind of code is taking too long (since its a specific filename based) and repetition of the same replace function, I would like to ask for a help on **how to make replace function loops for all the files in the same folder**.

A big appreciation for the answer.

Comment: It's not going to take any less time processing by putting everything in a loop - it'll just be smaller code and easier to maintain

Comment: I realise you are fairly new but a lot of the questions you ask are duplicates, please consider a quick search in google *(use the [`site:stackoverflow.com` trick](https://www.google.com/search?q=read+files+in+a+folder+vbscript&oq=read+files+in+a+folder+vbscript&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5935j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=site:stackoverflow.com+read+files+in+a+folder+vbscript) to search only [so])* before posting a question to avoid disappointment. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\windows")

Set Fls = fldr.files

For Each thing in Fls
    msgbox thing.path
Next
```

also `set contents = thing.readall`.

Comment: No sure what the down-vote is about?, this is the way to loop through all the files in a folder. The only thing I would say is the answer is a bit sparse.

Comment: This answer gave me idea on how to do it.